# change a backgroundcolor of button inside a view that has a UITapGestureRecognizer and buttons

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I have a view with a `UITapGestureRecognizer(numberoftapsrequired = 1)`,and this view also has some buttons.

I want to change background-color of a button which is tapped, select only one to change.

I don’t know how to get this button to change its background-color. Like this figure[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMzwU.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get rid of the gesture
2. Create a IBOutletCollection called buttons with your buttons in it
3. Add the following code to your VC.

   ```
   - (IBAction) didTapButton:(UIButton*) sender {
     sender.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; // or whatever

      // create a IBOutletCollection called buttons with your buttons in it
     for (UIButton *b in self.buttons) {
       if (b != sender) {
         b.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor]; // or whatever
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Set this action to the "touch up inside" for each button.

Comment: And I want to this changed backgroundcolor of button'title as a label'text

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I hope select the button'title as a tableview cell'textLabel when the button changing backgroundcolor.

Comment: Call the tableView's `selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:`

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correctly, you are adding the tap gesture in order to recognize the click event. No need to give tap gesture in the entire view. Give actions for each of the buttons and change their background colors in the action method

Comment: Actually,I hope select a tapped button's title as a Label's text,change its backgroundcolor just for user can know which one is selected.If I give actions for each of buttons, all buttons will change their backgrounds.I need only one which is tapped.

Comment: Give same action method for all buttons. Change the background color of the button which is clicked recently to whatever color you want. Change the background color of all other buttons to default color

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion.